# MySQL connection failed

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, php

I'm trying to access a page I created through localhost, but when I type in the url I get this error, apache2 is working, using ubuntu and php5.6

This is the error I get

```
Warning: MySQL connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/phpservermon/src/psm/Service/Database.php on line 525
Unable to establish database connection...
```

Here is my phpservermonitor config.php file

```
<?php
define('PSM_DB_PREFIX', 'monitor_');
define('PSM_DB_USER', 'root');
define('PSM_DB_PASS', 'my_password');
define('PSM_DB_NAME', 'phpservermon');
define('PSM_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('PSM_DB_PORT', '3306');
define('PSM_DEBUG', true);
```

I've tried various things such as trying to grant privileges to root using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'root'@'localhost' being the most notable one, also tried going to the file in the error, but had no luck in fixing it. I also had an error before which the problem was I didn't have the dom package for php.

PS: any info that might be helpful ask that I'll update the post.

Comment: In `phpservermon/config.php`, define proper database credentials.

Comment: Also, it should be `'username'@'host'` (like `'dan'@'localhost'`) not `'username'@'root'`.

Comment: Dan: I wrote it wrong in the question, but right the actual time, my bad.

Comment: Jos: I've checked that file as well, I think it's right I'm gonna edit it into the question, can you give it a look?

Comment: Can you login in mysql from the terminal with the root user?  And can you update your mysql version?

Comment: What @MohitMalviya says. Does this work: `mysql -u root -pmy_password monitor_phpservermon`?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work

Comment: Mohit Malviya: I can access mysql only by using sudo otherwise I can't. the error I get is:
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost', Is this because the password is weak or is it because I don't have permission, if it's because of the password strength how can I change the strength requirement

Comment: FIXED IT!! Was able to do it with this awnser
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost